# Help with a Differential Equation - I am getting the wrong Answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please consider the following problem. I feel I am going about it the right way but the answer I am getting is not right.
Problem:
Given that $y = x$ is a solution of
\begin{equation*}
(x^2 - 2x + 2)y'' - x^2 y' + xy = 0
\end{equation*}
find a linearly independent solution by reducing the order. Write the general
solution.
Answer:
Let $y = xv$. This gives us the following:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx} &=& x\frac{dv}{dx} + v \\
\frac{{d^2}y}{dx^2} &=& x\frac{{d^2}v}{dx^2} + \frac{dv}{dx} + \frac{dv}{dx}
    = x\frac{{d^2}v}{dx^2} +  2 \frac{dv}{dx} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we substitute back into the original differential equation.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^2 - 2x + 2)( x\frac{{d^2}v}{dx^2} +  2 \frac{dv}{dx})
    - x^2(x \frac{dv}{dx} + v) + x^2v &=& 0 \\
%
(x^2 - 2x + 2)( x\frac{{d^2}v}{dx^2} +  2 \frac{dv}{dx})
    - x^2(x \frac{dv}{dx}) &=& 0 \\
(x^2 - 2x + 2)( x\frac{{d^2}v}{dx^2} +  2 \frac{dv}{dx})
    - x^3\frac{dv}{dx} &=& 0 \\
(x^3 - 2x^2 + 2x )\frac{{d^2}v}{dx^2} +
    (2x^2 - 4x + 4 - x^3)\frac{dv}{dx} &=& 0 \\
( x^3 -2x^2 + 2x )\frac{{d^2}v}{dx^2} +
    (-x^3 + 2x^2 - 4x + 4)\frac{dv}{dx} &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $w = \frac{dv}{dx}$. This gives us the following:
\begin{eqnarray*}
( x^3 -2x^2 + 2x )\frac{dw}{dx} +
    (-x^3 + 2x^2 - 4x + 4)w &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^3-2x^2+2x}{dx} &=& \frac{(x^3-2x^2+4x-4)w}{dw} \\
\frac{x^3-2x^2+2x}{(x^3-2x^2+4x-4)dx} &=& \frac{w}{dw} \\
\frac{dw}{w} &=& \frac{(x^3-2x^2+4x-4)dx}{x^3-2x^2+2x} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Using an online integral calculator, I find:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln{|w|} &=& \ln(|x^2 - 2x +2|) - 2\ln{|x|} + x \\
\ln{|w|} &=& \ln(|x^2 - 2x +2|) - \ln{x^2} + x \\
w &=& \frac{(x^2-2x+2)e^x}{x^2} \\
\frac{dv}{dx} &=& \frac{(x^2-2x+2)e^x}{x^2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, if I integrate and find $v$ as a function of $x$ then I get a mess. Therefore, I am thinking that my solution is wrong.

The book's solution, which I feel is correct, is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
y &=& (x-2)e^x
\end{eqnarray*}

Could somebody please tell me where I went wrong?

This is not a homework problem.

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you have done so far, apart from missing out the constant of integration. You have arrived at $$A\frac yx=\int(1-\frac2x+\frac{2}{x^2})e^xdx$$
$$\Rightarrow A\frac{y}{x}=e^x-\int \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{2}{x}e^x)dx$$
and this leads directly to the solution you were looking for